# PostgreSQL in Python3 - SyntaxError in a create table statement with foreign key

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to create a table (basic_totals) which contains a foreign key to the primary key of another table (players). I'm saving the statement in a string as follows:

```
player_table_name = "players"
basic_table_name = "basic_totals"
basic_table_statement = '''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.{0} (
        id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        player_id SERIAL REFERENCES {1}(id),
        GP SMALLINT,
        3PTA SMALLINT,
        3PTM SMALLINT,
        FGA SMALLINT,
        FGM SMALLINT,
        FTA SMALLINT,
        FTM SMALLINT,
        PTS SMALLINT,
        FTM SMALLINT,
        PTS SMALLINT,
        REB SMALLINT,
        AST SMALLINT,
        STL SMALLINT,
        BLK SMALLINT,
        TO SMALLINT
    );'''.format(basic_table_name, player_table_name)
```

When trying to execute this statement using the connection's cursor (cursor.execute(basic_table_statement)), a SyntaxError is raised. 
Since the creation statement for the other table (players), which is done in the same way (minus the foreign key part), I assume the error is around this part.

What is wrong with my syntax and how can I debug it further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TO` is a [reserved keyword](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html). If you really insist on using it, you need to use [double quotes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) to escape it, e.g. `"to"`.

But once you do that, the name becomes case *sensitive*, so `TO` and `"TO"` are different names (because `TO` is folded to lowercase) .

However, using quoted identifiers is [strongly discouraged](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) and I **highly** recommend you find a different column name that does not need quoting.

Another problem are the column names `3PTA` and `3PTM`. Identifiers can not start with a number, so you need to find a different name for them as well (unless you want to use those dreaded double quotes).

Repeating the primary key column of the target table isn't necessary for an inline REFERENCES clause. You also defined the columns `FTM` and `PTS`twice.

Not the cause of an error, but another wrong choice is the type `serial` for player_id. `serial` isn't a data type. It's an abbreviation for an `integer` column which gets its default value from a sequence. Foreign key columns should never be defined as serial, as they reference an already generated value. So it should be `player_id integer REFERENCES {1}(id),`

Putting all of that together, the SQL should look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS some_table (
    id serial primary key,
    player_id integer references other_table,
    gp smallint,
    pta3 smallint, --<< here
    ptm3 smallint, --<< here
    fga smallint,
    fgm smallint,
    fta smallint, 
    ftm smallint,  --<< only once!
    pts smallint,  --<< only once!
    reb smallint,
    ast smallint,
    stl smallint,
    blk smallint,
    to_x smallint  --<< change here
);
```

---

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried changing the column name but it didn't fix the issue. Is there any way to debug it further?

Comment: @DrorRosenbach: the usual way to debug things like that, is to run the statement manually in a SQL client and check where exactly the error is reported. I did that and discovered all the errors you have in there